# str_replace - replace a set of strings with another set

Tags: php, string, replace, preg-replace, str-replace

Trying to write a function to correct case of a set of anacroyms, but can't see how to do it more logically..

I have this at the moment

```
$str = str_ireplace(" worda ", " Worda ", $str);
$str = str_ireplace(" wordb ", " woRrdb ", $str);
```

and so on, its a long list!

Is there a way I could have a set of strings to replace with a set of replacements? Aka:

```
worda = Worda
wordb = woRdb
```

I've seen other examples using preg_replace too but can't see a way to do it using that function either.

Answer (score 1):

You can give list of words in array as a parameter in [str_ireplace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php),

```
$str = str_ireplace(array("worda","wordb"),array("Worda","woRrdb"),$str);
```

More beautifully,

```
$searchWords = array("worda","wordb");
$replaceWords = array("Worda","woRrdb");
$str = str_ireplace($searchWords,$replaceWords,$str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, Looks like you don't want to right write the function `str_replace` multiple times.
So here is a solution for it:

you can take your data in an array like:

```
$arr = array("worda" => "Worda", "wordb" => "woRdb");
```

Hope this will be easy to do for you.

And then use the `foreach` loop for it:

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
  $str = str_ireplace($key, $value, $str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way you can do it using an associative array:

```
$words = array('worda' => 'Worda', 'wordb' => 'woRdb');
$str = str_ireplace(array_keys($words), array_values($words), $str);
```